# Rasterization of image

Tags: agda

I have a function `ℚ -> ℚ -> Bool` taking a Cartesian coordinate, where `true` stands for black and `false` for white. Is there any existing library that I can use to "rasterize" it into a bitmap image?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is out of scope for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm sure I've seen a lot of posts asking for libraries on this site...

Answer (score 1):

The PBM file format is a pretty simple text-based image file format. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm for a description. It's easy to write code to produce PBM files.

For the function `λ x y → x ≤ᵇ y`, the below code outputs the following PBM file contents:

```
P1
20 10
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The lines mean the following:

- `P1` is a magic number that identifies the file format.
- `20 10` are the width and height of the image.
- Each of the remaining lines represents one line of the image. `1` represents a black pixel and `0` a white pixel.

Put the above contents in a `.pbm` file (say, `test.pbm`) and you have something that you can open in image processing tools that support PBM files.

The `makePBM` function takes the width and height of the image to be produced, the x and y starting points in ℚ, the step to make in ℚ for each pixel in the x and y direction, and the `ℚ → ℚ → Bool` function to be evaluated.

`--guardedness` is only required, because I use `IO` for demonstration purposes.

```
{-# OPTIONS --guardedness #-}

module Raster where

open import Data.Bool using (Bool ; if_then_else_)
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ ; zero ; suc)
open import Data.Nat.Show using (show)
open import Data.Rational using (ℚ ; 0ℚ ; 1ℚ ; _+_ ; _≤ᵇ_)
open import Data.String using (String ; _++_)
open import IO using (Main ; run ; putStrLn)

-- width height offset-x offset-y step-x step-y function
makePBM : (w h : ℕ) → (ox oy sx sy : ℚ) → (ℚ → ℚ → Bool) → String
makePBM w h ox oy sx sy f = header ++ bitmap h oy
  where
  header : String
  header = "P1\n" ++ show w ++ " " ++ show h ++ "\n"

  row : (n : ℕ) → (x y : ℚ) → String
  row zero    x y = "\n"
  row (suc n) x y = pixel ++ " " ++ row n (x + sx) y
    where pixel = if f x y then "1" else "0"

  bitmap : (n : ℕ) → (y : ℚ) → String
  bitmap zero    y = ""
  bitmap (suc n) y = row w ox y ++ bitmap n (y + sy)

testPBM : String
testPBM = makePBM 20 10 0ℚ 0ℚ 1ℚ 1ℚ (λ x y → x ≤ᵇ y)

main : Main
main = run (putStrLn testPBM)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very surprised if there were. I'm not aware of any work on image manipulations in Agda.

Having said that, it should be relatively easy to do.

1. Create a `m x n` matrix of type `Vector (Vector ℕ m) n` from `Data.Vec.Functional` containing `(i,j)` at the `i`th row and `j`th column.
2. Map each (i,j) to the desired range of coordinates in the image.
3. Map the function `f : ℚ -> ℚ -> Bool` over each the entire matrix.

Comment: Yes. The point is that I don't know what the specification proposition for this function will be. I need to define rasterization.